# Is there anything wrong in this proof?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is there anything wrong in this proof?

> > To prove : any nontrivial subgroup(G say) of $(\mathbb R,+)$ is either dense in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb Z.l$, $l=inf\{x \in G:x>0\}$.

Is my approach correct? My proof:

> Let G be not dense in $\mathbb R$. So there exist $x\in \mathbb R$ and there exist $\epsilon>0$ so that $N_{\epsilon}(x)$ does contain no point of G. That is $G \subseteq \mathbb R-N_{\epsilon}(x)$.
>
> Since G is non-trivial, there exists $r$ non-zero in G. So $r \in \mathbb R-N_{\epsilon}(x)$. As G is a subgroup of $\mathbb R$ so $-r$ is in G too. So there is a $r>0$ in G.(may be more than one).
>
> We choose $l=inf\{x \in G:x>0\}$, now if $l\in G$ then definitely "$G= \mathbb Z.l$" now claim:$l$ is in G. If not $l$ is in $\mathbb R$. So, for all $\delta>0$,$N_{\delta}(l)$  contains point of $G$ contradicting $G$ is not dense in $\mathbb R$. so done.

Comment: Should be "either dense in $\mathbb R$ or **isomoprhic to** $\mathbb Z$." Since $\mathbb Z$ is itself a subgroup of $\mathbb R$, it is important to make the distinction.

Comment: "now if $l$ is $G$" - what? $l$ is a single real number and $G$ is (among others) a set of real numbers, how can $l=G$?

Comment: What I complained about has now been edited into "if $l\in G$ then definitela $G=\Bbb Z$" - which is wrong.

Comment: Yeah, the grammar in the last paragraph is confusing. I think you mean $G=l\mathbb Z$. Generally, bad to use $l$ as a variable, because it is sometimes hard to distinguish from $1$. Also, write $l\mathbb Z$ because $\mathbb Z.$ looked like the end of the sentence.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen It's is actually $G=\mathbb Z.l$," which is confusing. but probably means $l\mathbb Z$.

Comment: But the real problem is that just because $G$ isn't dense in all of $\mathbb R$, you haven't shown that $G$ can't be arbitrarily close to the single point, $\ell$. For example, the set $T=\{1+\frac{1}{n}\mid n\in\mathbb Z^{+}\}$ has points arbitrarily close to $1$ but is not dense in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: You should explain why $ l\not \in G\land \forall \delta>0\;(\;G\cap N_{\delta}(l)\ne \phi\;)$ implies that $G$ is dense....... Obviously $l\in G$ implies $ G\supset l.\mathbb Z,$  but you should explain why $l\in G$ implies $G=l.\mathbb Z.$

Comment: You could also show that if $0<l=\inf (G\cap \mathbb R^+)$ then $l\in G,$ because otherwise there exists $x\in G\cap (l,2l)$ and $y\in G\cap (l,l+x)$ implying $x-y\in G\cap (0,l)$ contrary to the def'n of $l.$

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts of the proof that are needed:

If $l=0$ then show that $G$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.

If $l>0$, show that $G=l\mathbb Z$.

I don't think you've proven either, although concentrating on this value $l$ is a good start.

I'll give a hint for the first part.

> If $l=0$, then for any $\epsilon>0$ there is an $r\in G$ such that $0<r<\epsilon,$ by the definition of $l$. Now, given any $x\in \mathbb R$, show that $N_{\epsilon}(x)$ must contain some $nr$ with $n$ an integer.